# "stop" filter behaving differently in Elasticsearch when using "_all"

Tags: search, elasticsearch, match

I'm trying to implement a [`match`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) search in [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), and I noticed that the behavior is different depending if I use `_all` or if a enter a specific string value as the field name of my query.

To give some context, I've created an index with the following settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "kstem",
            "word_delimiter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I create a document like:

```
{
  "name": "Hello.World"
}
```

And I execute a search using `_all` like:

```
 curl -d '{"query": { "match" : { "_all" : "hello" } }}' http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search
```

It will **correctly** match the document (since I'm using the `stop` filter to split the words at the dot), but if I execute this query instead:

```
curl -d '{"query": { "match" : { "name" : "hello" } }}' http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search
```

Nothing is being returned instead. How is this possible?

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? I verified this works fine on ES 1.3.4. I did not use cURL though. I used Sense to fire queries.

Comment: @Mouzer I'm using version 1.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Issue a GET for `/myindex/mytype/_mapping` and see if your index is configured the way you think it is. Meaning, see if that "name" field is `not_analyzed`, for example.

Even more, run the following query to see how `name` field is actually indexed:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "hello"
    }
  },
  "fielddata_fields": ["name"]
}
```

You should see something like this in the result:

```
    "fields": {
       "name": [
          "hello",
          "world"
       ]
    }
```

If you don't, then you know something's wrong with your mapping for the `name` field.